端末の貸し出しの際に、今までの貸し出し回数をフォームの回答完了画面にHTMLで表示したい
タブレットの貸し出しが多く、忘れることを防止することを目的に今までの貸出回数をHTMLで表示したいと考えております。
コードを作成し、GASへ入力していますがエラーが出てしまいます。
初心者のためお力を貸してください。
foamの回答では、１,名前（出席番号付き　例　１ 山田太郎）　２,借りる端末の番号　・・・となっています。
スプレットシートでは、A列　入力日時　B列　名前（出席番号付き）で表示されています。
初心者でして、どのように修正すればいいか分からず。お力添えください。
下記が現在のコードです。よろしくお願いいたします。
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var borrowerName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();

  // スプレッドシートのID、シート名、列番号などを設定
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('あなたのスプレッドシートのID');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('シート名');

  // スプレッドシートに書き込む（エラー処理を追加）
  try {
    // 既存の書き込み処理
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('スプレッドシートへの書き込み中にエラーが発生しました: ' + error);
  }

  // 貸出回数を取得（エラー処理を追加）
  var borrowerRow = ...; // 貸出者に対応する行を特定する処理
  var loanCount = sheet.getRange(borrowerRow, 2).getValue(); // 4列目が貸出回数カラムの場合

  // 回答者に表示するメッセージを作成
  var message = '〇〇さん、この端末の貸出は' + loanCount + '回目です。\n返却期限は〇〇日までです。';

  // フォームの確認画面にメッセージを表示するためのHTMLを作成
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>' + message + '</p>');
  e.range.getResponseContainer().addResponseMessage(html);
}


「うまくいかない」の部分をもう少し詳しく説明した方が回答も付きやすいと思います。質問は後からでも編集できるので、必要に応じて情報を追記してみてください。

エラーメッセージを貼ったほうがいいと思います
